# How to prevent ISP DNS from appearing in resolv.conf with a VPN connection?

Tags: dns, vpn

Ubuntu 15.10 and dns=dnsmasq is commented out in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

OpenVPN through NetworkManager.

Before I connect to a VPN /etc/resolv.conf contains

```
nameserver 2xx.xx.xx.xx <-- ISP DNS 1
nameserver 2xx.xx.xx.xx <-- ISP DNS 2
```

after a VPN connection /etc/resolv.conf contains

```
nameserver 1xx.xx.xx.xx <-- VPN DNS 1
nameserver 1xx.xx.xx.xx <-- VPN DNS 2
nameserver 2xx.xx.xx.xx <-- ISP DNS 1
```

The regular wired connection and the VPN have DNS servers set in network manager with automatic (only addresses). The ISP server shouldn't be there at all. What else can I change? (removing dns=dnsmasq was one change to stop split DNS).

Comment: Could you please provide additional details describing what software is used to connect to the VPN, and the type of VPN it is?

Comment: @ earthmeLon Updated to include OpenVPN and NetworkManager.